# Cannot add origin to my new git repository

Tags: windows, git, github, push, git-push

I have created a git repository and want to add some code files to it. I'm using git bash of Windows version. I ran these lines

```
    git init

    git status
```

This showed all files as none of them were tracked. Then

```
    git add .
    git commit "my_commit"

    git remote add origin https://github.com/userName/FileName.git
```

By running this command, got the following error

```
    bash: $'\302\226git': command not found
```

I have checked the path by running in cmd

```
    git --version
```

That resulted:

```
    git version 2.20.1.windows.1
```

Comment: Did you try that more than once?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, I have tried it more than once but no success

Comment: Did you type the command in each time or did you use the history of the Git bash (up-arrow key)?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I typed those commands

Answer (score 3):

You have a strange character between the command prompt and the `git` command. Remove it either moving the cursor to the `g` of `git` and hitting backspace several times, or yo can also:

1. Activate `vi mode` (supposing you are working with `git bash`): `set -o vi`
2. Once you have your command on screen, press `Esc` and the `v` key. A `vi` screen will open letting you edit the command.
3. Edit the command removing this character(s) and save with `:wq`. The command should execute normally.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The second part of vi mode I tried and that worked